# How do I define a cyclical enumeration?

Tags: haskell

I am interested in creating a cyclical enumeration where the first and last elements of the type are adjacent. The cardinal directions on a compass are an example of such an enumeration.

```
data Compass = North | East | South | West deriving (Enum)
```

The enumeration functions `pred` and `succ` would make functions that updated data with a `Compass` property declarative and easy to reason. There is no need explicitly define the behavior for every instance of `Compass`.

```
data Rotation = CounterClockwise | Clockwise
data Position = Position Compass Integer Integer

rotate :: Position -> Rotation -> Position
rotate (Position c x y) Clockwise = Position (succ c) x y
rotate (Position c x y) CounterClockwise = Position (pred c) x y
```

The problem is that `Enum` fails when `pred` or `succ` are called on the first and last `Compass` type repsectively. Is it possibile to define a cyclical enumeration that allows these functions to wrap to the beginning or end of the type list?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea. Some library functions might assume (?) that `Enum` is not cyclical e.g. `[West .. South]` will probably not work.

Comment: @chi I wonder if there is a sensible way of implementing `enumFromTo` and related methods in this case.

Comment: +1 to @SimonH.  I think it's monoid, not enumerate problem. So, `West <> x = x <> West = x`, `West <> North = North` and `North <> South = West`. It's similar to hours.

Comment: Define, yes. *Derive*, no.